# Strange margin between Divs

Tags: html, css

I encounter some strange behaviour in my code. I'm trying to put a row of div's with flexbox. This is a snippet:

```css
html{
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        background:black;
        font-family: Impact;
        margin: 0px;}
    
    .columns{
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
    
    }
    
    .col-1{
        display:flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    
        width:50%;
        background: green;
        color: white;
        height: 25vh;
        font-size: calc(5vw + 5vh + 2.5vmin);
        min-width: 200px;
        min-height:100px;
    
    }
    
    .col-2{
        display:flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    
        width:50%;
        color:white;
        background: red;
        height:25vh;
        font-size: calc(5vw + 5vh + 2.5vmin);
        min-width: 200px;
        min-height:100px;
    
    }
    
    .score-1 {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content: center;
        color:black;
        background:white;
        height:40vh;
        margin-left:9vw;
        margin-top:3vh;
        width:30%;
        min-width: 200px;
        min-height:100px;
    
        font-size:calc(12vw + 12vh + 2.5vmin);
    }
    
    
    .clock {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top:5vh;
        height:25vh;
        vertical-align:middle;
        font-size: calc(8vw + 8vh + 2.5vmin);
        background:white;
        color:cadetblue;
    
    }
    
    .score-2 {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content: center;
        color:black;
        background:white;
        height:40vh;
        margin-right:9vw;
        margin-top:3vh;
        width:30%;
        min-width: 200px;
        min-height:100px;
    
        font-size:calc(12vw + 12vh + 2.5vmin);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Skore</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class=columns>
            <div class="col col-1"> SOLDATOVA  </div>
            <div class="col col-2"> DROR Y B </div>
        </div>
    
        
        <div class=columns>
            <div class="col country-1"> 45 </div>
    
            <div class="col country-2"> 0 </div>
    
        </div>
    
    
        <div class=columns>
            <div class="score-1">45</div>
            <div class="clock">3:00</div><
            <div class="score-2">0</div>
    
        </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

There is a gap between `clock` and `score-2`, but  `columns` properties I'm using `justify-content: center;`, so I thought there will be no margins between the div's inside of it, so I'm unsure about what is happening here. Any way to resolve it?

Comment: you have an extra character `<` between your divs

Comment: @TemaniAfif ...You're absolutely right

Comment: So can this question be closed now? Was that typo all there was to it?